# grails neo4j config not adding nodes

Tags: grails, neo4j

I created the application using the instructions here:

http://blog.armbruster-it.de/2009/10/example-neo4j-with-grails/

I then added to `DataSource.groovy` this:

```
grails {
   neo4j {
      type = "embedded"
      location = "/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/"
      params = []
   }
}
```

Where my graph.db is located at `/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/community-1.8.1-unix/libexec/data/graph.db`

What should be going into this location.  I am adding new ndoes but when I run

```
start n=node(*) return n;
```

in the shell there is no new data.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your location should point right up to

```
/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/community-1.8.1-unix/libexec/data/graph.db
```

since that is where your neo4j database is located